# rare event / random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X$ be real valued random variable and $b \geq 0$. The problem concerns a bound for the probability
$$
\mathbb{P} ( X \geq b) 
$$
by
$$
\inf_{ \lambda \geq 0} \left ( e^{-\lambda b} \mathbb{E} ( e^{\lambda X}) \right ). 
$$
**question 1**
Under what minimal assumption on $X$, we are sure that we have a unique $\lambda^\star$ such that
$$
\inf_{ \lambda \geq 0} \left ( e^{-\lambda b} \mathbb{E} ( e^{\lambda X}) \right ) = e^{-\lambda_\star b} \mathbb{E} ( e^{\lambda_\star X} )
$$
**question 2** 
Second, if so, how to characterise it?

Comment: This comes under the heading of the Legendre or Legendre-Fenchel transform of the convex function $f(\lambda)=\log(E\exp(\lambda X))$. You need in general some technical condition ensuring that $f$ is "steep" (i.e., $f'$ is surjective).  See, for instance, the discussion in [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.0327.pdf) (look for *steep*) and in Rockafellar's *Convex Analysis*, section 26.  It suffices for $f(\lambda)<\infty$ for all $\lambda\in\mathbf R$ and for $f'(\lambda)$ to tend to $\infty$ as $|\lambda|\to\infty$.

Comment: thank you for the reference.